# Php ereg validating a form

Tags: php, forms, validation, ereg

Im validating a form and its easy to validate numbers, letters a-z and so on but when i got to the point where i need to validate a field which must contain only the characters (a-z and special characters such as öçğüiş) with at least one space only I am really stuck!

I tried the following and some other techniques without success:

```
function validateAlphaSpecial($value) {
    if (ereg("/^[\p{L}\s]+$/", $value, $regs)) {
           echo 'true';
         } else {
           echo 'false';
        } 
}
```

Has anyone got a solution for this. Thank you.

Comment: [ereg has been deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ereg.php). Have you considered [PCRE](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php)?

Comment: Ereg has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Relying on this feature is highly discouraged.

Comment: i never used such chars in regex match, but i heard that ereg is going to be deprecated

Comment: `Ereg` isn't going anywhere, deprecated or not. But you're already using a `preg_match` regex and meta patterns. So just use the right function.

Answer (score 0):

[Ereg has been deprecated](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ereg.php) as of PHP 5.3.0 like others said and you shouldn't use EREG.

The snippet below fits your validating requirement: **a-z and special characters such as öçğüiş with at least ONE SPACE**.

```
if( preg_match("/[\p{L}]\s{1,}+/u", $value) > 0 ) {
    echo 'Valid';
} else {
    echo 'Not valid';
}
```

**About /u modifier** [ from [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) ] :

> This modifier turns on additional functionality of PCRE that is
>   incompatible with Perl. Pattern strings are treated as UTF-8.